# Wrapping a story using decorator in storybook 5.2 - typescript / angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, storybook

I'm coming from storybook pre 5.2 using `storiesOf` whereby if i wanted to wrap my component I would use template.

EG

```
.add('Test', () => ({
  component: TestComponent,
  template: `
    <div class="wrapper">
      <test-component></test-component>...
```

In 5.2 the recommended way to write stories has changed and describes how to use decorators to achieve the same outcome https://storybook.js.org/docs/basics/writing-stories/#decorators. However I am using angular and struggling to find a solution as there are only react and vue examples. Both of which use specific functions / components

> In Vue projects you have to use the special component `<story/>` instead of the function parameter `storyFn` that is used in React projects

Using `template` as in the older spec I have tried the following

1. As an initial test that `template` works

```
export const Test = () => ({
  component: TestComponent,
  template: `Expecting just this text`
});
```

Outcome: See the text 'Expecting just this text'

2. Using `<TestComponent>`

```
export const Test = () => ({ component: TestComponent,
  template: <div class="wrapper"><TestComponent></TestComponent></div>
});
```

Outcome: Blank screen with `Template parse errors:
'CheckboxComponent' is not a known element:` suggesting use of `schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]

3. Using `<test-component>`

```
export const Test = () => ({
  component: TestComponent,
  template: `<div class="wrapper"><test-component></test-component></div>`
});
```

Outcome: Blank screen with `Template parse errors: 'CheckboxComponent' is not a known element:` suggesting use of schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]

For both 2 & 3 I tried adding

```
export const Test = () => ({
  component: TestComponent,
  addDecorator: moduleMetadata({
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
  }),
  template: `[tried both templates from 2 & 3]`
});
```

Outcome: Same errors appeared again

Could someone shed some light on how this would accomplished in typescript and where I am going wrong - thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the way to do it in 5.2 with the new story format. Fixed the `Template parse errors` by adding `[CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]` and declaring the component.

I'm also using the `docs` addOn https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/tree/master/addons/docs and added the capability for this.

I've included both storiesOf https://storybook.js.org/docs/formats/storiesof-api/ and the Component Story Format (CSF) https://storybook.js.org/docs/formats/component-story-format/ incase anyone else runs into difficulty.

storiesOf API

```
import { TestComponent } from './test.component';
import { storiesOf, moduleMetadata } from '@storybook/angular';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

storiesOf('Elements|Test', module)
  .addParameters({ // only needed for docs add-on
    component: TestComponent, 
    componentSubtitle: 'Subtitle'
    // docs: { page: null } uncomment this to disabled docs
  })
  .addDecorator(
    moduleMetadata({
      imports: [CommonModule],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      declarations: [TestComponent]
    })
  )
  .add('Test', () => ({
    component: TestComponent,
    template: `<div class="test">test text<app-test></app-test></div>`
  }));
```

CSF

```
import { TestComponent } from './test.component';
import { moduleMetadata, } from '@storybook/angular';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

export default {
  title: 'Elements|Test',
  component: TestComponent, // only needed for docs add-on
  parameters: { // only needed for docs add-on
    componentSubtitle: 'Subtitle.'
    // docs: { page: null } uncomment this to disabled docs
  },
  decorators: [
    moduleMetadata({
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      declarations: [TestComponent]
    })
  ]
};

export const Test = () => ({
  component: TestComponent,
  template: `<div class="text">test text<app-test></app-test></div>`
});
```